# Tkinter pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, pycharm

Estoy tratando de escribir mi código incluyen el modulo de tkinter en la plataforma de Pycharm para crear un script pero me rechaza al momento de llamarlo; tengo instalado el modulo tkinter y he probado con todas las importaciones pero no me da resultado; adjunto el código para su revisión:

```
#from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
#tkinter._test()
ventana = tk.tk()
ventana.title("Ventana")
#Ancho x alto
ventana.geometry("380x300")
#color de fondo
ventana.configure(background = "dark turquoise")

ventana.mainloop()
```

Aca pongo el resultado de la consola:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/proyectos_python/zona_sism/archivo_sismo/tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "C:\Users\Miguel Mogollòn\Desktop\proyectos_python\zona_sism\archivo_sismo\tkinter.py", line 5, in <module>
    ventana = tk.Tk()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya tengo la respuesta; lo que pasa que el scriptno tiene que guardarse con el mismo nombre del modulo, en este caso habia guardado el scrit con el nombre `tkinter.py`, lo cual tengo que cambiar el nombre del archivo.