# Error en Tkinter: NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.tittle("ventana de prueba")

root.mainloop()
```

como ven intento crear una ventana pero al compilar me salta este error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter.py", line 1, in 
    from tkinter import *
  File "E:\Programacion\Phyton\tkinter.py", line 3, in 
    root=Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Comment: Dos cosas, no llames a tu script `tkinter.py`, de hecho no uses nombres de módulos de la biblioteca estándar o de paquetes instalados para tus propios módulos, mirate esta pregunta con el mismo problema (en este caso con el modulo random): [Error en import: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104174/15089). Segundo, tienes un typo en `root.tittle`, sobra una `t` (`title`).

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/330243/tkinter-pycharm. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

`root.tittle("ventana de prueba")` esta incorrectamente escrito, ya que debe ser `root.title("ventana de prueba")` con una sola `t`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title("ventana de prueba")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo podría ser así:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("VENTANA DE PRUEBA")
ventana.mainloop()
```

Y logicamente guárdalo con otro nombre, que no sea uno reservado por python.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacerlo podría ser así:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("VENTANA DE PRUEBA")
ventana.mainloop()
```

Y logicamente guárdalo con otro nombre, que no sea uno reservado por python.